# VBA Save as PDF with Filename as Cell Value

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I am trying to save four sheets into a single PDF.  The code below is what I have so far.  When I use the ActiveSheet.Name command in the file name it works, however when I change it to a range for a cell that is dynamic it no longer works and errors out.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sheets(Array("Dashboard Pg 1", "Dashboard Pg 2", "Dashboard Pg 3", _
    "Dashboard Pg 4")).Select
Sheets("Dashboard Pg 1").Activate
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\Allen\Desktop\Projects\" & ActiveSheet.Range("K17").Value & ".pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
Sheets("Summary").Select
```

Comment: What is the evaluated value of K17? Is it possible that the value includes characters which are not legal characters for a filename?

Comment: Add ".pdf" at end of filename (`Filename:="C:\Users\Allen\Desktop\Projects\" & ActiveSheet.Range("K17").Value & ".pdf"`)?

Comment: No adding .pdf hasn't helped either. It still asks me to debug when running

Comment: I suspect that you are using some form of date in K17 and then some cell formatting magic to get what you want as a filename. If you use `.Value`, the date will be represented as a short date with forward slashes which cannot be used in a filename. Use `ActiveSheet.Range("K17").Text` to get the formatted value from the cell. Make *sure* that the cell is wide enough to display the full formatted text or you will end up with ###### as your PDF filename.

Comment: If "K17" is indeed a date, try something like this:
`Format(ActiveSheet.Range("K17"),"YYYY-MM-DD")`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim strFilename     As String
Dim rngRange        As Range

'Considering Sheet1 to be where you need to pick file name
Set rngRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K17")

'Create File name with dateStamp
strFilename = rngRange.Value & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd hhmmss")

Sheets(Array("Dashboard Pg 1", "Dashboard Pg 2", "Dashboard Pg 3", "Dashboard Pg 4")).Select
Sheets("Dashboard Pg 1").Activate
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\Allen\Desktop\Projects\" & strFilename & ".pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Sheets("Summary").Select
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly.  Seting the range like you did was what fixed the problem.  I appreciate everyone's help and responses.  Also, Jeeped, thank you for mentioning the width of the cell as that was also needed.

Comment: Two years later this answer helped me with my own VBA question :) Thank you

Comment: Three years and two months later this answer has helped me solve a delicate VBA problem I faced and which I could not find a solution anywhere else. With very little modification, voilà! Thank you all !

Comment: Six years and it is still working! Thanks @Jur Pertin!